# RestKit delete route

Tags: ios, rest, restkit

I'm working with RestKit on iOS and after setting a route:

`[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].router routeClass:[MyClass class] toResourcePath:@"/myresource" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];`

I would like to delete this route for "MyClass" class and replace with a new one.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way it to not use the sharedManager, but instead create one object manager for each of the two different things you want to do.